# Is it possible to authenticate using only the passcode, even device has touch id capability in ios, swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, passcode, localauthentication

I want to authenticate **only** using the `PassCode` even device has the `Touch ID` Feature. I'm using `.deviceOwnerAuthentication` evaluate policy method. when I use this,

> - If user has enrolled touch id --> alway ask for touch id
> - If use hasn't enrolled touch id --> then only ask for passcode

what I want is, even user has enrolled for the `touch id`, ask only for the `passcode`. hope your help with this.

Comment: Check if this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941863/how-to-use-passcode-lock-scene-in-my-app

Comment: @Melborne, yep but if we didn't enroll touch id, then it prompt default system passcode screen

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using Security framework using `SecAccessControl` by setting `SecAccessControlCreateFlags` as `.devicePasscode`.

Add a keychain item,

```
let secAccessControlbject: SecAccessControl = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                      kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
                                                                      .devicePasscode,
                                                                      nil)!
    let dataToStore = "AnyData".data(using: .utf8)!


    let insertQuery: NSDictionary = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecAttrAccessControl: secAccessControlbject,
        kSecAttrService: "PasscodeAuthentication",
        kSecValueData: dataToStore as Any,
    ]

    let insertStatus = SecItemAdd(insertQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
```

To authenticate with the Passcode screen access the saved item,

```
 let query: NSDictionary = [
        kSecClass:  kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecAttrService  : "PasscodeAuthentication",
        kSecUseOperationPrompt : "Sign in"
    ]

    var typeRef : CFTypeRef?

    let status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &typeRef) //This will prompt the passcode.

    if (status == errSecSuccess)
    {
       print("Authentication Success")
    }
```

Comment: Nandha, you are great! thanks for sharing this code. This really works! and I am greatful to you.. Thanks again for sharing the code.

Answer (score 0):

@Anuradh, As we cannot use iOS's passcode within our app for authentication, unless we use the TouchID I don't think there is a way to prompt just the default passcode screen. It's private API. Your best option is to use a custom passcode screen. You can check this 'ABPadLockScreen':https://github.com/abury/ABPadLockScreen

Comment: Thanx, but I don't want to use any third party