# Swift & deviceOwnerAuthentication : How to view passcode authentication board directly without going through Biometric Auth first?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, biometrics, passcode

I am trying to authenticate the user using the device passcode. And I want to view the passcode board directly. But with the code below, I always have to go through the biometric authentication first and fail in order to authenticate with a passcode. How do I get the passcode board directly?

```
import UIKit
import LocalAuthentication

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        authenticateUser()
    }
    
    func authenticateUser() {
        let context = LAContext()
        
        context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: "Please authenticate to proceed.") { (success, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if success {
                    self.resultLabel.text = "Success"
                    print("Success")
                }else{
                    self.resultLabel.text = "Failed"
                    print("Failed")
                    return
                }
            }
            
            
            
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Check here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lapolicy/deviceownerauthentication It says ... `If biometry is available, enrolled, and not disabled, the system uses that first`...

Comment: I found and tried this method below. It kinda worked but I have no clue what these code do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723662/is-it-possible-to-authenticate-using-only-the-passcode-even-device-has-touch-id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local authentication with passcode only is not available if the device has biometric capability and the user has enrolled.

You can prevent the fallback to passcode by using `LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics` but there is no policy that goes directly to the passcode option.

`LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthentication` will always try biometric first, if it is available, before falling back to device passcode.

Comment: I found and tried this method below. It kinda worked but I have no clue what these code do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723662/is-it-possible-to-authenticate-using-only-the-passcode-even-device-has-touch-id

Comment: That code puts an object in the keychain and retrieves set, setting the "require passcode" policy.  It is slightly different to simple local authentication.