# Xcode passcode - swift

Tags: swift, xcode, authentication, passcode

How do I get a system access code?
I want to block the controller in the application.
I do not want the user to create a new code but I want to use the system code.

I saw that other applications have such feature

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7ySz.jpg)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941863/how-to-use-passcode-lock-scene-in-my-app/

Comment: it's not what it needs. I need access to the lock code

Comment: You would likely need to use the [LocalAuthentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/) framework

Answer (score 2):

You *can't* get the users passcode, however you *can* authenticate a user and have them use their TouchID/FaceID

For this, you'll want to use the [LocalAuthentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/) framework.

Here's an example:

```
let myContext = LAContext()
let myLocalizedReasonString = <#String explaining why app needs authentication#>

var authError: NSError?
if #available(iOS 8.0, macOS 10.12.1, *) {
    if myContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &authError) {
        myContext.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: myLocalizedReasonString) { success, evaluateError in
            if success {
                // User authenticated successfully, take appropriate action
            } else {
                // User did not authenticate successfully, look at error and take appropriate action
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Could not evaluate policy; look at authError and present an appropriate message to user
    }
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Credit: [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/)